# Lightweight development web server with support for PHP v2

Tags: php, development-environment, rad

In line with this question:
[Lightweight web app server for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171655/lightweight-web-app-server-for-php)

The above question has been asked numerous times and answered exactly the same in all the cases I've found using google.  My question is similar to a degree but with a different desired goal: On demand development instances.

I have come up with a somewhat questionable solution to host arbitrary directories in my user account for the purpose of development testing.  I am not interested in custom vhosts but looking to emulate the behaviour I get when using paster or mongrel for Python & Ruby respectively.

Ubuntu 9.10 
TOXIC@~/ >APACHE_RUN_USER=$USER APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data apache2 -d ~/Desktop/ -c "Listen 2990"

Is there a better solution, could I do something similar with nginix or lighttpd?

Note:
   The above won't work correctly for stock environments without a copied & altered httpd.conf.

Update:
   The ideal goal is to mimic Paster, Webbrick, and Mongrel for rapid local development hosting.  For those light weight servers, it takes less then a minute to get a working instance running ( not factoring any DB support ).  Apache2 vhost is great but I've been using Apache2 for over ten years and it would be some sort of abomination hack to setup a new entry in /etc/hosts unless you have your own DNS, in which case a wildcard subdomain setup would probably work great.  EXCEPT one more problem,  it's pretty easy for me to know what is being hosted ( ex. by paster or mongeral ) just doing a sudo netstat -tulpn while there would be a good possibility of confusion in figure out which vhost is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/phpmvchelpers/wiki/script_serve

This is what I was looking to accomplish, the hack I made up isn't perfect but its functional.  Needs a couple more hours work to get the re-write rules dialed in and some more brush up work but its functional for Kohana & CakePHP... still working on Recess framework though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/)? It looks like it might fit your requirements:

1. Written in php, so once its up and running, serving pages should be pretty fast
2. Can be installed and run from a user's home directory

**Note:** I haven't tried it myself, I'm pretty happy using apache, but I thought I'd pass the info along

Comment: I've never even heard of it actually, going to check it out tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a lightweight solution *only* to save yourself time, I suggest you shouldn't.

You save time and probably lots and *lots* of headaches if you stick to the ol' LAMP software packages when it comes to development machines.

Comment: My experience with working with Pylons and Rails says otherwise, its much more conveniant to be able to check a project out of source control and launch it immediately for access to some port then to check the code out, add/edit a vhost entry, and then restart the web server.

Comment: If you're running Windows, you may want to give Wampserver a shot. Through tray icon, you can reach several tools, like Apacha aliases and service management with a few clicks. It easies my life for sure!

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) from Apache 2.x documentation may be an answer to your question.

I agree that development configuration should be as close as possible to production environment.

Comment: localhost:{numeric port number} is still a whole hell of a lot faster then any form of vhosting unless you have some sort of internal LAN dns to provide *.dev.local names.  I could be wrong but I don't think you can automatically tell Apache2's dynamic vhost module to host in incremental port numbers.

Comment: Perhaps not, but you can add more local IP's to your PC and use the IP-based option (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html#ipbased). Also, I haven't tested, but it might be possible that (if you used port) that it would be appended to the IP-based naming somehow.

Comment: @David - no need for real DNS -- check your /etc/hosts file